# Does copying many files in the same directory on an SSD result in increased wear of the blocks that store the concerned filesystem area?

Tags: linux, ssd, filesystems, cache, physical-wear

Assume several 1000's of files are copied in the same directory on an SSD. In such cases, the **concerned part of the filesystem area** must be updated after each newly created file, and it is highly probable this modifications will affect the same physical block (up to a limit). Now, the SSD itself has no idea whether a block holds filesystem information or something else, so it does not make sure on the firmware level that filesystem blocks are held in the SSD's cache. **So my question is:** is there an OS level **caching mechanism on the blocks holding the filesystem itself**? I'm specifically curious about how Linux/ext4 handles this (there is many information available about how caching of files written to block devices is done, but it is unclear **how the blocks of the filesystem area itself are cached**, if they are at all). I guess, they must be committed after each filesystem change, but in this case it would impose a huge extra wear on the blocks of the filesystem area in the above use case.

Comment: SSDs will do automatic wear levelling which spreads out the disk usage.

Comment: A lot depends on the quality of the SSD.  A good quality SSD can withstand many writes, and built in TRIM helps keep usage spread out.

Comment: SSDs have absolutely no concept of a directory. That's an OS construct.

Comment: It should be possible to write to a single SSD sector billions of times. It shouldn't matter if the wearout level was done right.

Comment: I think a lot of this depends on your ssd controller and write caching. https://linuxconfig.org/improve-hard-drive-write-speed-with-write-back-caching has a tutorial on tuning this with hdparm.

Comment: "*it is highly probable this modifications will affect the same physical block*" -- Incorrect assumption on your part. The filesystem and/or host computer can only access logical blocks using LBA. That's the ATA interface: logical block addressing, and no access to the underlying physical blocks (which will be managed by the Flash Translation Layer).